# Bulk collect in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

By using the bulk collect into, how you can detect when a query that does not return results to prevent an exception is thrown when trying to loop through the results?

Comment: Can you not just check whether the `COUNT` of the collection you `BULK COLLECT`ed the results into is zero?

Answer (score 2):

An example from documentation: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABCCJCB

```
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO names, sals LIMIT v_limit;
    EXIT WHEN names.COUNT = 0;
    print_results();
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
open rc for select descr from hardware;
loop
    fetch rc bulk collect into l_rows limit l_fetch_sizes(i);
    exit when rc%notfound;
end loop;
close rc;
```

**Exit When** finalize the **loop**.

To catch exception for **bulk collect DML operations** you could you **SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS**:

```
BEGIN
    -- DML operations
EXCEPTION
    WHEN operation_erros THEN
    l_error := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
    FOR ind IN 1 .. l_error LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || ind || ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(ind).ERROR_INDEX || ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(ind).ERROR_CODE));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Bulk collect will not raise a NO_DATA_FOUND exception.  (I tried to edit the answer but I keep getting errors.  The server does not like this answer or my edits, for some reason.)

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS` here.  `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS` is only used with bulk DML operations using `FORALL` ([source](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:349582300346524740)). Exceptions thrown during `BULK COLLECT` are thrown normally.  Your second code fragment is misleading.

Comment: You are right! I edit my answer.

Comment: Also, with your first code fragment, you should emphasise that any code that does stuff with `l_rows` comes before `EXIT WHEN ...`, not after it.  Otherwise you may end up skipping some data - see the 'Kicking the %NOTFOUND habit' section of [this Steven Feuerstein article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html) for more.